# How to print elapsed time in Matlab mapreduce

Tags: matlab, mapreduce

When doing a `mapreduce` one gets a progress box like the following:

```
********************************
*      MAPREDUCE PROGRESS      *
********************************
Map   0% Reduce   0%
Map 100% Reduce   0%
Map 100% Reduce  10%
```

Is it possible to add an elapsed time column, or some way to print out the elapse time each time a new progress row is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to print the elapsed time in the progress display. You can only toggle the display on and off.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mapreduce.html